# Передать значение из одной таблицы в другую в MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

Есть список `a = [2, 180, 14]`, из него первый элемент записываем в tab1 в столбец age, ему автоматически присваивается id_1 = 1, два других элемента  - в tab2

tab1:

```
+------+-------+
| id_1 |  age  |
+------+-------+
|  1   |   2   |
+------+-------+
```

Как значение из столбца id_1, передать в столбец id_2 у таблицы tab2?

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('INSERT INTO tab2(id_2, height, age1) VALUES ("?????", "180", "14")
```

Чтобы стало так:

```
+------+------+-------+-------+
|  id  | id_2 |height | age1  |
+------+------+-------+-------+
|   1  |   1  |  180  |  14   |
+------+------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: После записи в первую таблицу tab1 брать id и записывать оставшиеся данные с учётом сгенерированного id?

Comment: да, все верно..

Comment: Тогда тут важен ответ на вопрос, является ли пара `[id1, "2"]` уникальной. Потому что если нет, то вы не сможете по значению `"2"` получить ключ `id1`

Comment: Да, пара будет уникальной

Comment: id1 ведь автоинкремируемый элемент

Comment: Имелось в виду не пара, а может ли быть с разным `id1` одинаковые значение по типу `"2"`

Comment: по идее не будет повторяться, а можно сделать чтобы импортировалось в начале id1, "2", потом созданная строка редактировалась и создавалось поле например `p=id1` и тогда пара будет точно уникальной, или это одно и тоже получается?)